# Pycharm database introspection fails due to "Procedure <SCHEMA>.<DB>'.ASSOCIATE_SEMANTIC_CATEGORY_TAGS'" does not exist or not authorized

Tags: pycharm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with PyCharm and configured Snowflake DB connection.

Yesterday I have upgraded my M1 Pro mac, and ever since, DB introspect fails with the error:
"SQL compilation error:
Procedure 'DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.ASSOCIATE_SEMANTIC_CATEGORY_TAGS' does not exist or not  autorized."

I've searched and found similar [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15310) in DataGrip which was solved.
However, couldn't find anything that helped with PyCharm.

Following to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15312/Snowflake-introspection-fails-due-to-builtin-procedure) explanation:

"Snowflake recently changed "SHOW PROCEDURES" to include BUILTIN procedures:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SHOW-PROCEDURES-Command-Output-Includes-Both-User-created-and-Built-in-Stored-Procedures

Since users do not have permissions to access ..ASSOCIATE_SEMANTIC_CATEGORY_TAGS, introspection now fails".

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent PyCharm from introspecting procedure and functions.

Has anyone encountered and solved this issue?